# How to handle TreeView nodes with semicolons ;

Tags: c#, tfs, replace, treeview, nodes

I have a DevComponents.AdvTree which is populated with TFS work items. Each work item has a plain-text string called 'Folder' which holds the folder structure the item was saved under in a legacy system.

I have implemented functionality so that the dragging/dropping of treeview nodes automatically updates the 'Folder' string to match the full path of the node.

If a work item has a 'Folder' string such as:

```
"Folder1/Folder2/Folder3"
```

then the AdvTree represents this in the FullPath property as:

```
"Folder1;Folder2;Folder3"
```

If the node is dragged and dropped, the following code is executed:

```
    public static void UpdateNode(Node node)
    {
        string nodePath;
        WorkItem wi = (WorkItem)node.Tag;

        nodePath = node.FullPath.Replace(';', '/');

        wi.Open();
        wi.Fields[30].Value = nodePath; //The 'Folder' string'
        wi.Save();
        wi.Close();
        wi = null;
    }
```

This is fine, unless a semicolon `;` is included in the original 'Folder' string. In this case, the *valid* semicolon is replaced with a `/` too, causing the entire folder structure to change.

I thought about a solution whereby I'd replace all existing semicolons with another character or string, and display this as a `;` in the TreeView, but this seems very convoluted.

Could anyone offer a more simple solution?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Maybe you could use PathSeparator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.pathseparator.aspx

Comment: Hi JleruOHeP, Thanks for your reply. This is perfect. I originally commented to say that the AdvTree does not support the PathSeparator field, but this can be set at run time only. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JleruOHeP who answered this in the comments.

The character used to separate nodes when returning FullPath for the AdvTree can actually be changed at run time using the following code:

```
testCaseTreeView.PathSeparator = "/";
```

If using the standard TreeView, this can be set at design time.